# Why does this not put my Arduino Mega to sleep?

Tags: arduino-mega, sleep

I have the following program which is supposed to print the words "Program is on" once and then go to sleep. However it doesn't go to sleep and continues to print "Program is on" over and over again.

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Program is on");
  sleepNow();
}

void sleepNow()
{
  // Choose our preferred sleep mode:
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);
  // Set sleep enable (SE) bit:
  sleep_enable();
  // Put the device to sleep:
  sleep_mode();
  // Upon waking up, sketch continues from this point.
  sleep_disable();
}
```

Comment: Because *any* interrupt will wake it up from Idle, including those used by the Arduino libraries.

Comment: So what is waking up my Arduino in the code I have above? I don't have anything there besides the the `sleepNow()` function.

Comment: What is waking it up is what you don't see in the code above nonetheless exists.

Answer (score 1):

In idle sleep, the timer interrupts will wake the processor, as  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said in his comment.

A "higher" sleep mode works, however I had to add `Serial.flush ()` otherwise it only printed "P" because the processor goes to sleep before the serial output buffer has been emptied.

```c++
#include <avr/sleep.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Program is on");
  Serial.flush ();
  sleepNow();
}

void sleepNow()
{
  // Choose our preferred sleep mode:
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE);
  // Set sleep enable (SE) bit:
  sleep_enable();
  // Put the device to sleep:
  sleep_mode();
  // Upon waking up, sketch continues from this point.
  sleep_disable();
}
```

---

See [my page about power savings](http://www.gammon.com.au/power).

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to wake it up with you are using the `SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE` mode?

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: There are a few. See the "Power-save" row in the "Sleep Modes" section of the datasheet.

Comment: See [my page about power savings](http://www.gammon.com.au/power). Pin-change and external interrupts wake the processor from any sleep state. I think a serial interrupt will too. Also a watchdog timer interrupt can be used.